# Правильное подтверждение пользователя с помощью email mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Дело в том, что я использую node.js/mongoDB, когда пользователь регистрируется, его схема сохраняется в базе, и поле `active` равно `false` - Это значит что он не подтвержден. Ему отправляется письмо, где есть уникальный `url`, когда он по нему перейдёт, его поле `active` будет `true` - Это значит что он подтвержден.

Вот вопрос, ещё когда пользователь регистрируется я проверяю существует ли такой пользователь, (если у него поле `active` равно `true`) если да, то отправляю ошибку, если нет (пользователя с таким `email` или `username` нет, или его поле `active` равно `false`), то пропускаю дальше.

Я боюсь что если два пользователя зарегистрируются под таким же именем `username` и первый подтвердит почту быстрее второго, то второй не сможет зарегистрироватся. То есть при переходе по ссылке будет
неизвестная ошибка. Что в таком случае делать? Переправить пользователя назад и сказать что такое имя уже существует? Я думаю что это не совсем правильно.

Если я буду учитывать тех пользователей у которых поле `active` равно и `true` и `false`, тогда если пользователь введет неверный `email`, ему нужно будет создавать новое имя `username`, так как то имя уже будет зарезервировано. Не знаю что мне делать и что выбрать, об этом не пишут, я искал и ничего не нашел, буду очень благодарен если кто-то поможет, спасибо!

Comment: Проверку надо проводить по чему-то уникальному. Если в Вашей системе username не уникален, то будет не правильным опираться на него. Вернее будет, всю логику регистрации, основывать на email

Comment: Вы меня не поняли:), вопрос был в том, нужно ли мне проверять при регистрации, существует ли `username` в базе с полем `active` равно` false` - то есть пользователь с таким именем существует, но он не подтвержден (если не подтвержден то войти не может в систему), или проверять только те имена, которые имеют поле `active` равно `true`, то есть пользователь подтвержден? Или нужно проверять существует ли такое имя с полем `active = true` и так же `active = false` ?

Comment: Если `username` уникальное поле, то при регистрации, нужно проверять лишь на уникальность. Active - тут вообще не причем.  А вот когда юзер будет логинится (не путать с регистрацией), вот тогда и проверяйте на active

Comment: Допустим, пользователь `а` зарегистрировался под именем `alex_1`, но не подтвердил свою почту. Потом регистрируется пользователь `b`, и регистрируется под именем `alex_1`. Что мне делать? Мне нужно пользователю `b` сказать что такое имя существует, даже если пользователь `а` с таким именем ещё не подтвердил почту? Или пока пользователь `а` не подтвердил почту, это имя может взять пользователь `b` ?

Comment: `Что мне делать?` - сообщить пользователю `b`, что такое имя уже существует.  Чтобы не было неподтвержденных пользователей... можете установить срок для подтверждения (например, месяц). По истечению этого срока, можете удалить таких пользователей. Завсит от требований приложения

Comment: Если же, не активный  пользователь,  ЛОГИНИТСЯ  (вне зависимости от того `a` или `b`)  - то просите его подтвердить email. Для этого , так же, необходимо будет создать форму, для повторной отправки кода

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Я прошу подтвердить почту после того как он зарегистрируются. После чего говорю что бы он проверил почту, и перешел по ссылке. Я так понимаю, если он ввел почту неверно (при регистрации), то нужно ему дать шанс изменить почту, но только в текущий момент, пока он не закрыл вкладку? Ведь иначе, он должен будеть придумать другое имя.

Comment: то есть, если пользователь ввел не правильно почту, как позволить ему отправить другю почту с тем же именем и паролем?

Comment: Никак. Чтобы не было такой ситуации, необходимо 2 поля для вода мыла и перед отправкой проверять идентичность. Или же, пусть регистрируется еще раз. А Вы потом удалите неправильную регистрацию, как я выше описывал

Comment: Спасибо, решил что лучшим решением будет после регистрации позволить пользователю перейти на его страницу, а там он уже сможет поменять что хочет. Если он не подтвердит аккаунт в течении 2-х дней, его аккаунт удалится. Ещё раз спасибо большое!)